# AngularJS create directive dynamically inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

### **Problem Statement**

I have below two parent and child data structures like this where on parent div header click dynamic directive for showing corresponding child records are created.

But when I click on parent header link corresponding children items are not showing in table structure.Can anyone see where it is wrong?

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
    app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.parents = [
            { parent_id: '1', name: 'Parent 1', count: '2' },
            { parent_id: '2', name: 'Parent 2', count: '3' },
            { parent_id: '3', name: 'Parent 3', count: '1' }
        ];

        $scope.getchild= function (parent) {
            var children_list = [
            { id: '1', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 1' },
            { id: '2', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 2' },
            { id: '3', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 3' },
            { id: '4', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 4' },
            { id: '5', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 5' },
            { id: '6', parent_id: '3', name: 'Test Child 6' }
            ];

            var directive_name = 'clschild_' + parent.parent_id;
            app.directive(directive_name, function() {

                var child_html = '<div class="panel-body"> \
                    <table ng-attr-id="tblchild_'+ parent.parent_id + '" class="table table-hover"> \
                        <thead> \
                            <tr> \
                                <td>Name</td> \
                            </tr> \
                        </thead> \
                        <tbody> \
                            <tr ng-repeat="child in children"> \
                                <td>{{child.name}}</td> \
                            </tr> \
                        </tbody> \
                    </table> \
                </div>';
                return {
                    template: child_html,
                    link: function (scope) {
                        scope.$apply(function () { scope.children = children_list; });
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });

</script>
```

and corresponding HTML is

```
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="parent in parents">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" ng-href="#divchild_{{parent.id}}" ng-click="getchild(parent);" class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">{{parent.name}}</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-attr-id="divchild_{{parent.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="clschild_{{parent.id}}">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    aaa
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is a <kbd>[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8cXcFYl6wvZCLcbXNSZS?p=preview)</kbd> example

I am learning angularjs day by day so please bear with me if I am wrong somewhere in implementing above.

Your help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I think a better approach will be, create a directive, and use `ng-repeat` to show all the data.

Comment: you cannot create directive inside the controller

Comment: Thanks so you mean two separate directives for parent and children.

Comment: I think your way to show the children is wrong! you have to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another test case of your problem take a look at this one hope you get some thing useful. http://plnkr.co/edit/MMZXa7BViOQBEuH87Kyd?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clicked_parent = 0;
    $scope.parents = [
        { id: '1', name: 'Test Parent 1', count: '2' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Test Parent 2', count: '3' },
        { id: '3', name: 'Test Parent 3', count: '1' }
    ];

    $scope.children_list = [
      { id: '1', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 1' },
      { id: '2', parent_id: '1', name: 'Test Child 2' },
      { id: '3', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 3' },
      { id: '4', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 4' },
      { id: '5', parent_id: '2', name: 'Test Child 5' },
      { id: '6', parent_id: '3', name: 'Test Child 6' }
    ];

    $scope.isParentTagClicked = false;
    $scope.set_parent_id = function(_id){
      $scope.isParentTagClicked = !$scope.isParentTagClicked;
      if ($scope.isParentTagClicked){
        $scope.clicked_parent = _id; 
      }else{
        $scope.clicked_parent     = 0;
      }
    };

}]);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

  <head>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="TestCtrl">

      <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="parent in parents">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="set_parent_id(parent.id)">{{parent.id}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="child in children_list" ng-show="child.parent_id == clicked_parent" ng-if="child.parent_id == parent.id">
          Panel content - {{child.parent_id}}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example helps you

> If you want to create dynamic directives you have to use all attribute of them like scope, template, ngTransclude, replace and ...
>
> This example show you how to bind data from controller to one directive using scope.

```js
angular.module("app", []);
 angular.module("app").controller("ctrl", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.parents = [
        { id: 1, name: "Test Parent 1", count: "2" },
        { id: 2, name: "Test Parent 2", count: "3" },
        { id: 3, name: "Test Parent 3", count: "1" }
    ];

    $scope.children = [
        { id: 1, parent_id: 1, name: "Test Child 1" },
        { id: 1, parent_id: 1, name: "Test Child 2" },
        { id: 1, parent_id: 2, name: "Test Child 3" },
        { id: 1, parent_id: 2, name: "Test Child 4" },
        { id: 1, parent_id: 2, name: "Test Child 5" },
        { id: 1, parent_id: 3, name: "Test Child 6" }
    ];


   $scope.getChild = function(parentId) {
     var findChildren = $filter("filter")($scope.children, {
       parent_id: parentId
     });
     $scope.setChild = findChildren;
   }

 });

 angular.module("app").directive("directive", function() {
   var template = "<div class=\"panel-body\">" +
     "<table class=\"table table-hover\">" +
     "<thead>" +
     "<tr>" +
     "<td>Name</td>" +
     "</tr>" +
     "</thead>" +
     "<tbody>" +
     "<tr ng-repeat=\"child in children\">" +
     "<td>{{child.name}}</td>" +
     "</tr>" +
     "</tbody>" +
     "</table>" +
     "</div>";
   return {
     scope: {
       child: "="
     },
     template: template,
     link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

       scope.$watch("child", function(newValue) {
         if (newValue)
           scope.children = newValue;
       }, true);

     }
   };
 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>parent list</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="parent in parents">
        {{parent.name}}

        <button ng-click="getChild(parent.id)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right">click to get child</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr />

    <h1>child list</h1>

    <directive child="setChild"></directive>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```